# If the Nothing type is at the bottom of the class hierarchy, why can I not call any conceivable method on it?

Tags: scala, types

The scala type `Nothing` represents (as I understand it) the bottom of the type hierarchy, also denoted by the symbol ⊥. That is, `Nothing` is a sub-type of any given type. The requirement for a `Nothing` type is [explained well by James Iry](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/08/getting-to-bottom-of-nothing-at-all.html) for those of us without a theoretical background in type theory!

So my question is, if `Nothing` is a subtype of every type, why can I not call any type's methods on `Nothing`? Obviously, I cannot instantiate Nothing but why doesn't the following compile?

```
var n: Nothing = _

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println(n.length) //compile error: value length is not a member of Nothing
}
```

Surely as `Nothing` is a subtype of `String` this should be OK? Note that the following compiles just fine!

```
var n: Nothing = _

def foo(s: String) : Int =  s.length

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println(foo(n))
}
```

as does:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println(n.asInstanceOf[String].length) 
}
```

Comment: Another thing to consider is that in `n.length` there's no way for Scala to know which method `length` you're talking about -- and you need to know that before you can even think about whether its arguments (or `this` argument) has the right type. In `foo(n)` it's already clear which.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While `Nothing` is a subtype of everything, it does not *inherit* any method except for those in `Any`.  This is because `Nothing` is more geared toward the functional end of the language.  It's necessary for things like `Option` and `List`, but only as a **type**, not as a class.

The distinction here is a bit weird for those coming from an object-oriented background, but the fact is that subtyping as a concept is very distinct from OOP.  Granted, object-oriented really implies subtyping in some form, but the reverse is not true.  Benjamin Pierce's *Types and Programming Languages* does a good job of presenting the language [F_<](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_F-sub) (pronounced "F sub"), which serves as a minimal example of a language with subtyping (but not OO).

Now, with all that said, I do agree that the fact that `Nothing` is immune from the normal inheritance rules does seem a bit inconsistent.  However, from a theoretical standpoint, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `Nothing` could accept any method, and perform a standard operation on all of them (throwing an exception). That wouldn't be very useful, though.

By presenting a compile error, the compiler is warning the programmer that a type he most likely didn't want, `Nothing`, got inferred somehow at a certain point in the code.

Comment: But I can call `toString` on nothing, I was just wondering if there's some ugliness which treats Nothing as a special case from the compiler's perspective. Or whether my type-theory was awry and the methods a type supports *and the type itself* are not necessarily correlated

Comment: I suppose the idea was to make a compile-time verification where possible.  It is not ugly, it is good, when instead of a runtime error you get a compile-time one.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `toString` on `Nothing` variable because of it s defintion:
`final trait Nothing extends Any`
And toString is member of `Any`. I think scala compiler treat's `Nothing` in type bounds only and treats it like any other trait on all over cases. Letting invoke any method on variable with type of `Nothing` will be very strange I think.

Comment: But there's still some special treatment going on. From the type *signature* of `Nothing`, I can't tell that it extends every other type.

Comment: Ah so it's a trait, not a class. So you can only call the methods that are explicitly defined by the trait. That would explain a lot.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: Well special treatment described in specification so compiler treats it specially in terms of type bounds , e.g. for each type T following is true:  Nothing < T < Any, but beside of that why compiler should treat Nothing trait any more special? No references of that in spec.