What is the difference between the types Null and Null & T where T <: AnyRef?
Look at the following method
def toOption[T <: AnyRef](value: T | Null): Option[T] = 
    value match {
        case null => None
        case content: T => Some(content)
    }

If you inspect the content pattern variable, the type is T | T & Null, which I guess is the result of the the intersection of the type of the scrutinee value: T | Null and the type of the matched pattern element: T.
What calls my attention is the second operand of the | operator. Shouldn't the T & Null part be simplified to Null by the compiler when T<:AnyRef leaving T | Null as the type of content? What is the difference between the types Null and T & Null?
If the definition of the intersection A & B was that it represents values that are members of both A and B then:

if the values represented by T included null then the set of values that are members of both T and Null would contain only the null value;
if the values represented by T did not include the null then the set of values that are members of both T and Null would be empty (Nothing).

Therefore, T & Null = Null | Nothing = Null when T <: AnyRef.
If the definition of the intersection A & B was that a value conforms to A & B implies that it conforms to both A and B then:

if null conforms to T then only null would conform to both T and Null;
if null does not conform to T then no value would conform to both T and Null.

Therefore T & Null = Null | Nothing = Null when T <: AnyRef.
Am I missing something or the compiler has a bug?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I was using intelliJ for the inspection. Later, to confirm, I used a macro to display which is the type of content according to the compiler, and the result was T. Very different from what the intelliJ inspection shows.
I was blaming the compiler for a bug of the intelliJ inspector. Sorry.
Here is the macro:
inline def typeOf[A](a: A): String = ${typeOfMacro[A]('{a})}

def typeOfMacro[A : Type](a: Expr[A])(using q: Quotes): Expr[String] = 
    Expr(q.reflect.TypeRepr.of[A].show)

Anyway, the scala REPL is not simplifying A & Null to Null when A <: AnyRef.
scala> val text: String & Null = null
val text: String & Null = null

So the question still prevails.
Curiously REPL also does not simplify A & Nothing to Nothing either.

Edit 2: According to type theory there is no type X such that A & X is the same to X for any A. So the simplification I expected would be incorrect. REPL is giving the correct type. So the answer to my question is yes, I was missing something.

Scastie / metals doesn't show me that weird type, but it does warm me about the runtime check: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/9vrLo5lGRzuvSNmu1rVagA/4

Yes, the type check warning arises from Scala's absence of a feature that TypeScript possesses: control flow dependent type narrowing.
That is very unfortunate. I would appreciate scala to support it in the near future. Adding @unchecked everywhere is tedious and error prone.

This has nothing to do with "control flow dependent type narrowing". This is just a type erasure because you are actually doing a class check thus the full type is lost at runtime.

I think it does. If control flow dependent type narrowing was supported then the type of value at the second case would be T and no type ascription would be necessary.

Fair, but that is another issue. The language spec says that union types must be used through class checks which is why I usually avoid them.

Quite a lot of questions, so I'll start from basics.
Scala is based on DOT calculus. In Scala every type T is a type segment [Lower, Upper]. Scala types is a lattice (with respect to <:, &, |): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_(order)
T <: AnyRef doesn't imply T >: Null, nor vice versa.
T <: AnyRef means the type segment [Nothing, AnyRef]. T >: Null means [Null, Any].
(Nothing <: AnyVal <: Any, Nothing <: Null <: AnyRef <: Any, Nothing != Null != AnyRef != AnyVal != Any.)
AnyRef is the supertype of all reference types. Null is the subtype of all reference types. Null is inhabited only by null.
Nothing is the subtype of all types (including Null: Nothing <: Null, Nothing != Null). It's inhabited by no (normal) values. But being uninhabited by (normal) values doesn't mean that Nothing is uninhabited by anything at all. There are terms of this type: t: Nothing, there are abstract types/type parameters intersecting with this type: T >: Nothing (and in type-level programming types are more important, values, whether they exist or not, are less important), there are not so normal values (divergences, bottom values) like
@tailrec
def infiniteRecursion(): Nothing = infiniteRecursion()

def throwException(): Nothing = throw new RuntimeException("error")

def foo[T <: AnyRef](t: => T): Unit = ()

foo[Nothing](infiniteRecursion()) // compiles, runs, successfully finishes
foo[Nothing](throwException())  // compiles, runs, successfully finishes

def foo[T <: AnyRef](t: T): Unit = ()

foo[Nothing](infiniteRecursion()) // compiles, runs forever
foo[Nothing](throwException()) // compiles, runs, throws exception

If T <: AnyRef implied T >: Null, then foo[Nothing](infiniteRecursion()), foo[Nothing](throwException()) wouldn't compile.
If you want both T <: AnyRef and T >: Null then just specify both type bounds:
def foo[T >: Null <: AnyRef] = ...

Shouldn't the T & Null part be simplified to Null by the compiler when T <: AnyRef

No, it shouldn't. It should when T >: Null (including T >: Null <: AnyRef).

What is the difference between the types Null and T & Null?

If T = Nothing then T & Null = Nothing & Null = Nothing != Null. If T >: Null then T & Null = Null. If T <: Null (i.e. T belongs to the segment [Nothing, Null]) then T & Null = T. If T is just some type then T & Null is just some type <: T and <: Null (actually, the maximal such type), generally different from T and Null.

If the definition of the intersection ...

if the values...
if the values...


I guess we already discussed a year ago that types are not sets (of values):
Why does a self annotated trait is not assignable to the type of self?
https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/91330/what-exactly-is-the-semantic-difference-between-set-and-type
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489369/difference-between-a-type-and-a-set
https://planetmath.org/11typetheoryversussettheory
If two types have equal sets of values of these types, this doesn't make types equal.
For example below types Nat, Succ[N], _0, _1, _2, ... are abstract and have no values. But they are quite different types. If types were sets then all these types Nat, Succ[N], _0, _1, _2, ... would be the same set (namely, the empty set).
type Nat
type _0 <: Nat
type Succ[N <: Nat] <: Nat

trait Add[N <: Nat, M <: Nat] {
  type Out <: Nat
}
object Add {
  type Aux[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, Out0 <: Nat] = Add[N, M] { type Out = Out0 }

  implicit def zeroAdd[M <: Nat]: Aux[_0, M, M] = null
  implicit def succAdd[N <: Nat, M <: Nat](implicit
    add: Add[N, M]
  ): Aux[Succ[N], M, Succ[add.Out]] = null
}

type _1 = Succ[_0]
type _2 = Succ[_1]
type _3 = Succ[_2]
type _4 = Succ[_3]
type _5 = Succ[_4]

implicitly[Add.Aux[_2, _3, _5]] // compiles

trait ToInt[N <: Nat] {
  def apply(): Int
}
object ToInt {
  implicit val zeroToInt: ToInt[_0] = () => 0
  implicit def succToInt[N <: Nat](implicit toInt: ToInt[N]): ToInt[Succ[N]] =
    () => toInt() + 1
}

trait AddToInt[N <: Nat, M <: Nat] {
  def apply(): Int
}
object AddToInt {
  implicit def mkAddToInt[N <: Nat, M <: Nat, Sum <: Nat](implicit
    add: Add.Aux[N, M, Sum],
    toInt: ToInt[Sum]
  ): AddToInt[N, M] = () => toInt()
}

def addToInt[N <: Nat, M <: Nat](implicit addToInt: AddToInt[N, M]): Int =
  addToInt()

addToInt[_2, _3] // 5


According to type theory there is no type X such that A & X is the same to X for any A.

Actually, in Scala type system X is Nothing.


in Scala type system X is Nothing <

If that was true then the compiler could simplify A & Nothing to Nothing, but it doesn't.
If I am correct, Nothing is a scala hack to solve some situations. But isn't a real type according to type theory.
A & B should have all the members of A and B, so for "Nothing & A = Nothing for any A" be true Nothing should have the members of all posible types, nevertheless it has none. Or at least the compiler complains when accessing a member of a variable with type Nothing.

@Readren "then the compiler could simplify A & Nothing to Nothing, but it doesn't" Surely it does: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/wLBUOMnTQnSqjAH9f0Os6w/2 "But isn't a real type" Surely it's a real type. "according to type theory" Did you actually read that in some textbook on type theory? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type "Nothing should have the members of all posible types" Already discussed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728541/if-the-nothing-type-is-at-the-bottom-of-the-class-hierarchy-why-can-i-not-call

@Readren "only to support exceptions" Not only exceptions but also infinite recursion (it's not so easy to detect at compile time whether recursion is finite). Nothing is just the minimal element of the type lattice like Any is the maximal element. Nothing is important for type inference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64969830/5249621


Did you actually read that in some textbook<  It was chatGPT who told me that lie. :S

