Sharing a path dependent type between objects
As a proof of concept, I'm creating a simple graph implementation in Scala. I would like to know at compile time which node belongs to which graph and forbid mixing them. I'm representing the graph as an adjacency list, which I would like to be immutable. This means that modifying the graph creates a new Graph object. Each graph needs to have a path dependent node id type, which is always a subtype of Int, and this type somehow needs to be shared among different objects (but NOT objects representing graphs with distinct identities.)
The best solution I've been able to come up with is this:
trait NodeType:
  type Repr

object NodeType:
  def apply(): NodeType =
    new NodeType { type Repr = Int }

case class Node[A, N](value: A, neighbors: Set[N])

// Would be simpler if I could parameterize it as Graph[A]
case class Graph[A, N](nodes: Vector[Node[A, N]]):
  def addNode(value: A): (Graph[A, N], N) =
    val graph = copy(nodes = nodes :+ new Node(value, Set()))
    (graph, nodes.length) // compiler error -- Found: Int, Required: N

  def connect(node1: N, node2: N): Graph[A, N]:
    ...

But this doesn't compile and I'd ideally like to be able to write something like:
val graph: Graph[String] = Graph()
val node: graph.Node = graph.addNode("foo")

Is there some feature of Scala that would make this approach workable?

"But having the node type as a generic argument is messy" Not clear. Please be more specific. "I also get lots of type errors where the compiler is expecting some nodeType.Repr and gets an Int instead (or vice versa)" Please provide reproduction. The code you provided doesn't reproduce compile errors https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ze0VtUdRRPqxGkkfY8g3Kg Please see How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

What is the reason to introduce type Repr <: Int and override it then in an implementation with just Int and not something more specific: override type Repr = Int?

@DmytroMitin: I was attempting to make the compiler understand that I can always use the NodeType.Repr type as an index to a Vector, but that didn't work. I edited my question for clarity and to make the error reproducible.

Your code is still quite confusing. You introduced NodeType and Repr and do not use them anywhere further on. What are A and N? A is the value of a node. But what is N? Is it subtype of Node or subtype of Int? Is it number of nodes? What is Set? Is it standard scala.collection.immutable.Set? What is the meaning of Set[N] then if N is a subtype of Int?

Should addNode return Graph or Node?

@DmytroMitin: It returns a tuple of a new Graph and a reference to the new node created.

You answered my comment about addNode. Could you also answer my previous comment about N? (If comments are collapsed, please expand them.) Thanks.

@DmytroMitin: Sorry, didn't see the other comment. I understand why the code is confusing. I tried to keep it brief, just enough to illustrate my question. I meant the N type to represent the Repr type of some NodeType object. So it's equivalent to an Int but is associated with the "identity" of a particular graph. The essence of my question is how do I make a given graph (a series of objects with nodes in common) have an "identity" such that nodes from one graph can't be used in another graph. And yes, Set is the standard immutable Set type. At this point I'm leaning towards using a monad.

I've also learned since posting this that Int is final and so has no subtypes. I just need to wrap Int in an object so it's path-dependent.

Well, Int is a final class, so it can't have subclasses. But Int can have subtypes (for example singleton types 1, 2, 3...). Subclasses and subtypes are different things. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77991742 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76105137 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78457851 and links there.

Normally the reason for path-dependent types is to have types x.T (or x.y.z.T) different for different x. Classical examples are Board+Coordinate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693067/what-is-meant-by-scalas-path-dependent-types and Animal+Food http://lampwww.epfl.ch/~amin/dot/fpdt.pdf If you define type T = Int then x.T is still path-dependent type but this dependency is trivial, all x.T are Int.
